# Magento Partially Updated. Want to re-update

Tags: php, magento

I have a site with magento version 1.8.1.0. For upgrading, I logged into magento connect and selected Version 1.9.2.2 for Mage_All_Latest and clicked "Commit Changes" button. After some time, the process of upgrading stopped, showing an error of file permission. When I clicked the refresh button, the website was neither going to the magento connect page, nor to the home page. Each request was being redirected to this url: http://siteurl/downloader
I replaced the app folder and some other files with the backups I had. The site was then loading. When I logged into magento connect, It was showing version 1.9.2.2. But the admin footer is still showing 1.8.1.0. I checked the site with http://magereport.com/ but it was showing some security risks which are solved in version 1.9.2.2. So the update was not completely done. I want to update the site again but I find no way to do this. I tried with reinstalling "Mage_All_latest" but it does nothing. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the upgrade guide from Magento: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_details.html or copy the latest version over your current installation (with the disadvantage that removed files in comparison with your version will not be removed).