# magento update 1.7.0.1 > 1.9.2.2 trough mage connect

Tags: magento, updating

Just a short while ago I updated a mage 1.7.0.1 with the magento connect manager to magento 1.9.2.2 .

In the connect manager, I chose "Manage Existing Extensions" and then checked the "Check for updates" button next to it!

After that connect manager comes with a list to be updated. I checked all because I wanted to update from version 1.7.0.1 to 1.9.2.2.

After doing this, the only thing that is working now is the downloader, no front-end and no back-end.

**I already tried:**
Deleted  /var/cache and /var/session.
Deleted Maintenance.flag.
Deleted all extensions that not belong to magento general.
Tried to reinstall all with the downloader after removing extensions that not belong to mage general.

Still no go! Some help or other options to try would be appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Dennie

Comment: Almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33936139/622945